# How can I have 2 skyboxes in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, glm-math, skybox

I'm trying to make a skybox that can change with a button.
My solution for this is to bind my skyboxes and load my textures in the following way:

```
//SkyBox
    GLuint skyboxVBO, skyboxVAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &skyboxVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &skyboxVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, skyboxVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(skyboxVertices), &skyboxVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid *)0);

    // Load textures
    vector<const GLchar*> facesN;
    facesN.push_back("SkyBox/night/right.tga");
    facesN.push_back("SkyBox/night/left.tga");
    facesN.push_back("SkyBox/night/top.tga");
    facesN.push_back("SkyBox/night/bottom.tga");
    facesN.push_back("SkyBox/night/back.tga");
    facesN.push_back("SkyBox/night/front.tga");

    GLuint cubemapTextureN = TextureLoading::LoadCubemap(facesN);

    vector<const GLchar*> faces;
    faces.push_back("SkyBox/day/right.tga");
    faces.push_back("SkyBox/day/left.tga");
    faces.push_back("SkyBox/day/top.tga");
    faces.push_back("SkyBox/day/bottom.tga");
    faces.push_back("SkyBox/day/back.tga");
    faces.push_back("SkyBox/day/front.tga");

    GLuint cubemapTexture = TextureLoading::LoadCubemap(faces);
```

Then, in the program loop I draw the skybox with the following:

```
// Draw skybox as last
        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  // Change depth function so depth test passes when values are equal to depth buffer's content
        SkyBoxshader.Use();
        view = glm::mat4(glm::mat3(camera.GetViewMatrix()));    // Remove any translation component of the view matrix
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(SkyBoxshader.Program, "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(SkyBoxshader.Program, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        // skybox cube
        glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        if (daytime == 1.0f) {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubemapTexture);
        }
        else {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, cubemapTextureN);
        }
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // Set depth function back to default
```

In theory, whenever I press the button that changes the value of `daytime`, the skybox should change its textures to `cubemapTextureN` and, with another press of the button, change back to `cubemapTexture`. Instead, it just draws the texture that was loaded last, `cubemapTexture` in this case.
I already tested `daytime` and it does change, so it's not that.

Also, I tried loading `cubemapTextureN` after `cubemapTexture` and by doing so `cubemapTextureN` gets drawn instead, but still no change. I'm assuming somehow while loading the second textures, the first ones get updated, which shouldn't happen since they have different names, unless i'm understanding it wrong.

Easy solution would be to just make models of the entire skyboxes and work with that, but if possible I want to see if I can use this solution.

Edit:
These are the Shaders for the skybox.
Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform samplerCube skybox;

void main()
{
    color = texture(skybox, TexCoords);
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec3 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;


void main()
{
    vec4 pos = projection * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = pos.xyww;
    TexCoords = position;
}
```

And their use:
`Shader SkyBoxshader("Shaders/SkyBox.vs", "Shaders/SkyBox.frag");`

Also, if this is usefull, this is the header with the definition of `TextureLoading`, which contains `LoadCubemap`

```
#pragma once
// GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Other Libs
#include "stb_image.h"

// Other includes
#include "Model.h"
#include <vector>


class TextureLoading
{
public:
    static GLuint LoadTexture(GLchar *path)
    {
        unsigned int textureID;
        glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

        int width, height, nrComponents;
        unsigned char *data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
        if (data)
        {
            GLenum format;
            if (nrComponents == 1)
                format = GL_RED;
            else if (nrComponents == 3)
                format = GL_RGB;
            else if (nrComponents == 4)
                format = GL_RGBA;

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

            stbi_image_free(data);

        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << path << std::endl;
            stbi_image_free(data);
        }

        return textureID;
    }


    static GLuint LoadCubemap(vector<const GLchar * > faces)
    {
        GLuint textureID;
        glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

        int width, height, nrChannels;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
        {
            unsigned char *data = stbi_load(faces[i], &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
            if (data)
            {
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
                stbi_image_free(data);
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Cubemap texture failed to load at path: " << faces[i] << std::endl;
                stbi_image_free(data);
            }
        }
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);

        return textureID;
    }

};
```

Comment: Why GL_TEXTURE1, not GL_TEXTURE0? And please show your shader and glUniform* bindings.

Comment: Most likely your shader uses texture unit 0 (`GL_TEXTURE0`) which stays bound to the last texture you loaded (because you must be calling `glBindTexture` somewhere in `LoadCubemap`.) Please show a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the post adding the shader and `Texture.h` which contains `LoadCubemap`. I'm honestly not sure why It's using `GL_Texture1` instead of `GL_Texture0`, but I did try using `GL_Texture0` and the textures just dissapear.

Comment: @LollStarr: You don't set the `skybox` uniform anywhere. If you bind your texture to `GL_TEXTURE1` then you need to set the uniform to the integer value `1`. Read about [how to bind textures to samplers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Binding_textures_to_samplers).